# MD5 hash generator

Tags: c#, cryptography

I made this code for a simple WinForm for my school project where I want to add other hash and encryption algorithms. I have made it following the algorithm of the official [RFC 1321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321) and the Wikipedia page. I checked if the algorithm is correct by generating a hash and indeed it's working. However, are there any optimisable points and should I remove/add something?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eigenMD5
{
    class MD5
    {
        // Zie Wikipedia
        protected readonly static uint[] T = new uint[64] 
            {   
                0xd76aa478,0xe8c7b756,0x242070db,0xc1bdceee,
                0xf57c0faf,0x4787c62a,0xa8304613,0xfd469501,
                0x698098d8,0x8b44f7af,0xffff5bb1,0x895cd7be,
                0x6b901122,0xfd987193,0xa679438e,0x49b40821,
                0xf61e2562,0xc040b340,0x265e5a51,0xe9b6c7aa,
                0xd62f105d,0x2441453,0xd8a1e681,0xe7d3fbc8,
                0x21e1cde6,0xc33707d6,0xf4d50d87,0x455a14ed,
                0xa9e3e905,0xfcefa3f8,0x676f02d9,0x8d2a4c8a,
                0xfffa3942,0x8771f681,0x6d9d6122,0xfde5380c,
                0xa4beea44,0x4bdecfa9,0xf6bb4b60,0xbebfbc70,
                0x289b7ec6,0xeaa127fa,0xd4ef3085,0x4881d05,
                0xd9d4d039,0xe6db99e5,0x1fa27cf8,0xc4ac5665,
                0xf4292244,0x432aff97,0xab9423a7,0xfc93a039,
                0x655b59c3,0x8f0ccc92,0xffeff47d,0x85845dd1,
                0x6fa87e4f,0xfe2ce6e0,0xa3014314,0x4e0811a1,
                0xf7537e82,0xbd3af235,0x2ad7d2bb,0xeb86d391
            };

        // Zie Wikipedia
        protected readonly static int[] s = new int[64]
        {
            7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22,
            5,  9, 14, 20, 5,  9, 14, 20, 5,  9, 14, 20, 5,  9, 14, 20, 
            4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 
            6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21
        };


        // Standaard waarden
        uint A = 0x67452301;
        uint B = 0xEFCDAB89;
        uint C = 0x98BADCFE;
        uint D = 0X10325476;

        protected uint[] X = new uint[16];
        protected byte[] m_byteInput;

        public MD5(string s)
        {
            m_byteInput = new byte[s.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                m_byteInput[i] = (byte)s[i];
            }

        }

        public string createMD5()
        {
            byte[] bMsg;
            uint N;

            bMsg = padBuffer();

            N = (uint)(bMsg.Length * 8) / 32;

            for (uint i = 0; i < N / 16; i++)
            {
                makeBlock(bMsg, i);
                calcTransform();
            }

            string s = ReverseByte(A).ToString("X8") +
                        ReverseByte(B).ToString("X8") +
                        ReverseByte(C).ToString("X8") +
                        ReverseByte(D).ToString("X8") ;
            return s;
        }

        private static uint ReverseByte(uint uiNumber)
        {
            return (((uiNumber & 0x000000ff) << 24) |
                   (  uiNumber               >> 24) |
                   (( uiNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 8)  |
                   (( uiNumber & 0x0000ff00) << 8)) ;
        }

        protected void calcTransform()
        {
            uint AA = A, BB = B, CC = C, DD = D;
            uint F = 0;
            int g = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                if (i >= 0 && i <= 15)
                {
                    F = ((BB & CC) | (~(BB) & DD));
                    g = i;
                }
                else if (i >= 16 && i <= 31)
                {
                    F = ((BB & DD) | (CC & ~DD));
                    g = (5 * i + 1) % 16;
                }
                else if (i >= 32 && i <= 47)
                {
                    F = (BB ^ CC ^ DD);
                    g = (3 * i + 5) % 16;
                }
                else if (i >= 48 && i <= 63)
                {
                    F = (CC ^ (BB | ~DD));
                    g = (7 * i) % 16;
                }
                uint dtemp = DD;
                DD = CC;
                CC = BB;
                uint dtempt = AA + F + T[i] + X[g];
                dtempt = (dtempt << s[i]) | (dtempt >> (32 - s[i]));
                BB = BB + dtempt;
                AA = dtemp;
            }

            A += AA;
            B += BB;
            C += CC;
            D += DD;
        }

        protected void makeBlock(byte[] bMsg, uint block)
        {
            block = block << 6;
            for (uint i = 0; i < 61; i += 4)
            {
                X[i>>2] = (((uint)bMsg[block+(i+3)]) << 24) |
                          (((uint)bMsg[block+(i+2)]) << 16) |
                          (((uint)bMsg[block+(i+1)]) << 8)  |
                          (((uint)bMsg[block+(i)] ))        ;
            }
        }
        protected byte[] padBuffer()
        {
            uint pad;
            byte[] bMsg;
            ulong sizeMsg;
            uint sizeMsgBuff;

            int temp = (448 - ((m_byteInput.Length * 8) % 512));

            pad = (uint)((temp + 512) % 512);

            if (pad == 0)
            {
                pad = 512;
            }

            sizeMsgBuff = (uint)((m_byteInput.Length) + (pad / 8) + 8);
            sizeMsg = (ulong)m_byteInput.Length * 8;
            bMsg = new byte[sizeMsgBuff];

            for (int i = 0; i < m_byteInput.Length; i++)
            {
                bMsg[i] = m_byteInput[i];
            }

            bMsg[m_byteInput.Length] |= 0x80;

            for (int i = 8; i > 0; i--)
            {
                bMsg[sizeMsgBuff - i] = (byte)(sizeMsg >> ((8 - i) * 8) & 0x00000000000000ff);
            }

            return bMsg;
                
        }
    }
}
```

An MD5 hash can be generated by calling `MD5 test = MD5(yourstring)` and then doing `test.createMD5()`. I am aware that I could make the generation more direct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Why isn't this class `sealed` which I would expect of a security targeting class. By omitting the `sealed` keyword together with these `protected` variables and methods opens this class to vulnerabilities. Why should this class ever be inherited from ?
- according to the [NET naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing. So for instance `calcTransform()` should become `CalcTransform()` or better without abbreviation `CalculateTransform()`.
- according to the same naming guidelines variables should be named using `camelCase` casing. So for instance `uint[] X` should be `uint[] x`. If variable names doesn't have a special domain meaning, they should be as descriptive than possible.

---

> ```
> protected byte[] m_byteInput;
>
> public MD5(string s)
> {
>     m_byteInput = new byte[s.Length];
>     for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
>     {
>         m_byteInput[i] = (byte)s[i];
>     }
>
> }
> ```

`m_byteInput` is no where changed in your code so better make it `private readonly` to be sure that you don't accidential change it.

> ```
> protected readonly static uint[] T = new uint[64] 
>         {   
>             0xd76aa478,0xe8c7b756,0x242070db,0xc1bdceee,
>             0xf57c0faf,0x4787c62a,0xa8304613,0xfd469501, 
>             ...
> ```

If you initialize a array at the creation, you don't need to add the `length` of it. So this can become

```
private readonly static uint[] t = new uint[] 
        {   
            0xd76aa478,0xe8c7b756,0x242070db,0xc1bdceee,
            0xf57c0faf,0x4787c62a,0xa8304613,0xfd469501,
            ...
```

The same is true for `int[] s`.

> ```
> public string createMD5()
> {
>     byte[] bMsg;
>     uint N;
>
>     bMsg = padBuffer();
>
>     N = (uint)(bMsg.Length * 8) / 32;
>
>     for (uint i = 0; i < N / 16; i++)
>     {
>         makeBlock(bMsg, i);
>         calcTransform();
>     }
>
>     string s = ReverseByte(A).ToString("X8") +
>                 ReverseByte(B).ToString("X8") +
>                 ReverseByte(C).ToString("X8") +
>                 ReverseByte(D).ToString("X8") ;
>     return s;
> }
> ```

Hungarian notation [should not be used anymore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx). Your IDE will show you the used type if you hoover over a variables name. If you have a method named `padBuffer` it would be more obvious to name the variable which holds the returned value like `paddedBuffer`.

Having the variable `string s` doesn't add any value here. Just return the concated values.

By assigning a value at the declaration your code will become shorter and better readable like so

```
public string CreateMD5()
{
    byte[] paddedBuffer = PadBuffer();

    uint N = (uint)(bMsg.Length * 8) / 32;

    for (uint i = 0; i < N / 16; i++)
    {
        makeBlock(paddedBuffer, i);
        calcTransform();
    }

    return ReverseByte(A).ToString("X8") +
                ReverseByte(B).ToString("X8") +
                ReverseByte(C).ToString("X8") +
                ReverseByte(D).ToString("X8") ;
}
```

That is much clearer, isn't it ?

> ```
> protected void calcTransform()
> {
>     uint AA = A, BB = B, CC = C, DD = D;
>     uint F = 0;
>     int g = 0;
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
>     {
>         if (i >= 0 && i <= 15)
>         {
>             F = ((BB & CC) | (~(BB) & DD));
>             g = i;
>         }
>         else if (i >= 16 && i <= 31)
>         {
>             F = ((BB & DD) | (CC & ~DD));
>             g = (5 * i + 1) % 16;
>         }
>         else if (i >= 32 && i <= 47)
>         {
>             F = (BB ^ CC ^ DD);
>             g = (3 * i + 5) % 16;
>         }
>         else if (i >= 48 && i <= 63)
>         {
>             F = (CC ^ (BB | ~DD));
>             g = (7 * i) % 16;
>         }
>         uint dtemp = DD;
>         DD = CC;
>         CC = BB;
>         uint dtempt = AA + F + T[i] + X[g];
>         dtempt = (dtempt << s[i]) | (dtempt >> (32 - s[i]));
>         BB = BB + dtempt;
>         AA = dtemp;
>     }
>
>     A += AA;
>     B += BB;
>     C += CC;
>     D += DD;
> }
> ```

Declarations of multiple variables on the same line should be avoided because it reduces readability of the code.

Because you have written the `if` conditions from low to high you can omit the checking of the lower value of `i`.

After this `if..else if` statement you are doing this

> ```
> uint dtemp = DD;
> DD = CC;
> CC = BB;
> uint dtempt = AA + F + T[i] + X[g];
> dtempt = (dtempt << s[i]) | (dtempt >> (32 - s[i]));
> BB = BB + dtempt;
> AA = dtemp;
> ```

it is very hard to distinguish between a variable `dtemp` and another `dtempt`.

Maybe `currentDD` (or `swapedDD`) and `calculatedValue` would be better.

Implementing these points will lead to

```
private void CalcTransform()
{
    uint AA = A;
    uint BB = B;
    uint CC = C;
    uint DD = D;
    uint F = 0;
    int g = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        if (i <= 15)
        {
            F = ((BB & CC) | (~(BB) & DD));
            g = i;
        }
        else if (i <= 31)
        {
            F = ((BB & DD) | (CC & ~DD));
            g = (5 * i + 1) % 16;
        }
        else if (i <= 47)
        {
            F = (BB ^ CC ^ DD);
            g = (3 * i + 5) % 16;
        }
        else if (i <= 63)
        {
            F = (CC ^ (BB | ~DD));
            g = (7 * i) % 16;
        }
        uint currentDD = DD;
        DD = CC;
        CC = BB;
        uint calculatedValue = AA + F + T[i] + X[g];
        calculatedValue = (calculatedValue << s[i]) | (calculatedValue >> (32 - s[i]));
        BB = BB + calculatedValue;
        AA = currentDD;
    }

    A += AA;
    B += BB;
    C += CC;
    D += DD;
}
```

---

> ```
> protected byte[] padBuffer()
> {
>     uint pad;
>     byte[] bMsg;
>     ulong sizeMsg;
>     uint sizeMsgBuff;
>
>     int temp = (448 - ((m_byteInput.Length * 8) % 512));
>
>     pad = (uint)((temp + 512) % 512);
>
>     if (pad == 0)
>     {
>         pad = 512;
>     }
>
>     sizeMsgBuff = (uint)((m_byteInput.Length) + (pad / 8) + 8);
>     sizeMsg = (ulong)m_byteInput.Length * 8;
>     bMsg = new byte[sizeMsgBuff];
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < m_byteInput.Length; i++)
>     {
>         bMsg[i] = m_byteInput[i];
>     }
>
>     bMsg[m_byteInput.Length] |= 0x80;
>
>     for (int i = 8; i > 0; i--)
>     {
>         bMsg[sizeMsgBuff - i] = (byte)(sizeMsg >> ((8 - i) * 8) & 0x00000000000000ff);
>     }
>
>     return bMsg;
>
> }
> ```

Variables should be declared as near as possible to their usage. This can be easily achieved by assigning the values at declaration.

A variable named `sizeMsgBuff` would be more meaningful if it would be named `messageBufferSize` or `bufferSize`. The same applies for `sizeMsg` -> `messageSize`.

Regarding `0x00000000000000ff`, this is a magic number, which should be extracted to a meaningful (maybe domain specific named) constant. In addition, it could be more easily expressed like `0xff`.

This loop

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < m_byteInput.Length; i++)
> {
>     bMsg[i] = m_byteInput[i];
> }
> ```

can be replaced by a call to `Array.Copy()`.

Applying these points leads to

```
private byte[] PadBuffer()
{

    uint pad = (uint)(((448 - ((m_byteInput.Length * 8) % 512)) + 512) % 512);

    if (pad == 0)
    {
        pad = 512;
    }

    uint bufferSize = (uint)((m_byteInput.Length) + (pad / 8) + 8);
    ulong messageSize = (ulong)m_byteInput.Length * 8;

    byte[] paddedBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    Array.Copy(m_byteInput, paddedBuffer, m_byteInput.Length);

    paddedBuffer[m_byteInput.Length] |= 0x80;

    for (int i = 8; i > 0; i--)
    {
        paddedBuffer[bufferSize - i] = (byte)(messageSize >> ((8 - i) * 8) & 0xff);
    }

    return paddedBuffer;

}
```